# Recommended GPUs for Tensorflow

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I understand that Tensorflow requires (for GPU computation) a GPU with Nvidia Compute Capability >= 3.0. There are many such GPUs to choose from. The gaming oriented GPUs, e.g. GeForce models, are much less expensive than the compute-oriented models, e.g. Tesla. My limited undertanding is that the compute-oriented models may lack video output (not needed for computation) and that the gaming models may be doing 32-bit math instead of 64. Assuming that Tensorflow uses (or prefers) 64-bit, does this mean that the gaming models will not work or will produce deficient results if used with Tensorflow? What attributes should one look for in choosing a GPU to use with Tensorflow?

Comment: deep learning does not prefer double (64 bit), on the contrary - one of the major selling points for the next generation of nvidia cards is them being able to do fast 16-bit floating point calculations.

Comment: Gaming cards are a better value for money for deep learning unless you are running a 24/7 deployment. For instance Titan X is faster and a lot cheaper than K20

Comment: FYI since writing the original post above I purchased and have been running a GTX 1080 Ti and it is, in a word, wonderful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gaming GPUs can work quite well. You want a very recent GPU with lots of memory and CUDA cores. Most people training neural nets these days on GPU use 32 bit floats.

Answer (score 6):

The GPU-enabled version of TensorFlow has the following requirements:

- 64-bit Linux
- Python 2.7
- NVIDIA CUDA® 7.5 (CUDA 8.0 required for Pascal GPUs)
- NVIDIA cuDNN v4.0 (minimum) or v5.1 (recommended)

TensorFlow GPU support requires having a GPU card with NVidia Compute Capability >= 3.0. Supported cards include but are not limited to:

- NVidia Titan
- NVidia Titan X
- NVidia K20
- NVidia K40

You can see their official docs [Tensorflow GPU support](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup)